# ServiceStack - How do I use existing IOC?

Tags: c#, servicestack, autofac

We have an existing MVC3 project and use Autofac for DI.

To provide RESTful services, we are intending to use ServiceStack. How do we make ServiceStack use existing Bootstrapper.cs that initialises autofac?

Our existing Bootrapper.cs:

```
 public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static ContainerBuilder builder;
        public static void Initialise()
        {
            builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack documentation offers an example [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#use-autofac). You just need to implement an adapter to forward resolving to Autofac.

**Update:**

You can return container instance after you registered your services:

```
public static IContainer Initialise() 
{ 
    builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly); 
    Register types here builder.Register(x => new FormsAuthWrapper()).As<IFormsAuthentication>();
    builder.Register(x => new ServiceDbContext()).As<DbContext>().As<ServiceDbContext>().InstancePerHttpReques‌​t();
    var container = builder.Build(); 
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); 
    return container;
}
```

Then you can use this instance to create the adapter.

```
IContainerAdapter adapter = new AutofacIocAdapter(Bootstrapper.Initialise());
container.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But it seems that App_Start gets executed first followed by Bootstrapper.cs, which means we have code at two places. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Black-Baba What is the content of this Bootstrapper.cs?

Comment: Our Bootstrapper holds code to initialise various classes required for MVC application.